# Cant convert black diamonds with question marks to readable text

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars

I have this text "纽约黄金" from an api. When I use `file_get_contents` to get the data it displays `ŦԼ�ƽ�`.

I manage to convert it using this code.

```
$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $string);
```

My problem is when I upload it to server, instead of showing the readable text, it displays nothing.

Hope you help me.

Comment: are you serving the web pages UTF-8?

Comment: @tim yes, I check also the charset of that text its UTF-8

Comment: Detect encoding is a misnomer; it guesses. If you know the encoding, use that and skip the guessing. If the API is over HTTP, the response header will likely declare the encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)